# Oracle: Understanding and replicating ORA-14130 UNIQUE constraints mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

Tags: oracle, partition

everyone!
I'm facing this error (ORA-14130 UNIQUE constraints mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION) on my shared development environment and I can't fix it just because I don't completely understand it.

Let's create these three tables:

What index/constraint should I create on which table for the ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION fails with ORA-14130?

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_1 AS
SELECT  level id, timestamp'2000-11-02 09:00:00' fecha
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY level <= 100000 ;

CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_2 AS
SELECT level id, timestamp'2001-09-10 13:00:00' fecha
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 100000 ;

CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST
( 
    id, 
    fecha
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( fecha )
(
    PARTITION year_2000 VALUES LESS THAN ( timestamp'2000-12-02 00:00:00' ),
    PARTITION year_2001 VALUES LESS THAN ( timestamp'2001-10-10 00:00:00' )
)
AS
SELECT  1, timestamp'2000-11-02 09:00:00'
FROM    dual
WHERE   1=0;

--What should I add here for the ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION to throw an ORA-14130?
ALTER TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST EXCHANGE PARTITION year_2000 WITH table TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_1;
```

Thank u SO much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a unique constraint on the partition table to get the error. So, do this before the exchange:

```
alter table TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST add constraint ukk unique (id, fecha);
```

and then you need to do the exchange like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST EXCHANGE PARTITION year_2000 WITH table TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_1 including indexes;
```

Comment: Humm that throws an ORA-14098: Index mismatch for tables in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION, not an ORA-14130

Comment: This is what I got. "SQL> ALTER TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST EXCHANGE PARTITION year_2000 WITH table TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_1 including indexes;
ALTER TABLE TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_TEST EXCHANGE PARTITION year_2000 WITH table TMP_DEBUG_BORRAR_DATOS_1 including indexes
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14130: UNIQUE constraints mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
". It depends really on how you did it. Did you add a unique index, or a unique constraint?

Comment: You're completely right! I added UNIQUE INDEX and PKs, but not an unique constraint. My bad! I'll gladly accept the answer ;)